# How to hanlde array in python data frame for xml string

Tags: python-3.x

I have below xml that i need to convert into row format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OperationStatus xmlns:ns2="summaries">
   <EventId>123456</EventId>
   <notificationId>123456</notificationId>
   <userDetails>
      <clientId>123456</clientId>
      <userId>123456</userId>
      <groupIds>
         <groupId>123456</groupId>
      </groupIds>
   </userDetails>
</OperationStatus>
```

This is my python code

```
# !pip install xmltodict
import xmltodict
xml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OperationStatus xmlns:ns2="summaries">
   <EventId>123456</EventId>
   <notificationId>123456</notificationId>
   <userDetails>
      <clientId>123456</clientId>
      <userId>123456</userId>
      <groupIds>
         <groupId>123456</groupId>
         <groupId>123457</groupId>
      </groupIds>
   </userDetails>
</OperationStatus>"""

d = xmltodict.parse(xml)
print(d)
col1=d['OperationStatus']['userDetails']['clientId']
#print(col1)
col2=d['OperationStatus']['userDetails']['userId']
#print(col2)
col3=d['OperationStatus']['userDetails']['groupIds']['groupId']
#print(col3)
Result = col1 + ',' + col2 + ',' + col3 + '\n'
print(Result)
```

when i run above code i get error

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

Can some one please help how ow can we handle array in this use case ?
We need to print two line in this .

The output that is expected is

```
123456,123456,123456
123456,123456,123457
```

Comment: Either `col1`, `col2`, or `col3` is a `list`, and you're trying to concatenate it with a string (`','`). You may want to use a method that converts a list to a string, like `"".join(your_list)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

Any iterable can be joined (e.g, `list`, `tuple`, `dict`, `set`)  by `"".join()`

[Python String join() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp)

```
import xmltodict
xml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OperationStatus xmlns:ns2="summaries">
   <EventId>123456</EventId>
   <notificationId>123456</notificationId>
   <userDetails>
      <clientId>123456</clientId>
      <userId>123456</userId>
      <groupIds>
         <groupId>123456</groupId>
         <groupId>123457</groupId>
      </groupIds>
   </userDetails>
</OperationStatus>"""

d = xmltodict.parse(xml)
print(d)
col1=d['OperationStatus']['userDetails']['clientId']
#print(col1)
col2=d['OperationStatus']['userDetails']['userId']
#print(col2)
col3=d['OperationStatus']['userDetails']['groupIds']['groupId']
#print(col3)
Result = "".join(col1)+','+"".join(col2)+','+"".join(col3[0])+'\n'+ "".join(col1)+','+"".join(col2)+','+"".join(col3[1])
print(Result)
```

or use `For Loop`:

```
for i in range(len(col3)):
    Result = "".join(col1)+','+"".join(col2)+','+"".join(col3[i])
```

output:

```
123456,123456,123456
123456,123456,123457
```

Comment: I am trying to print this in two lines `123456,123456,123456
123456,123456,123457`

Comment: You can use the index. I changed the above code according to your output